# Payoff of a Contract

Tags: finance

Let $S$ be the value of a stock that evolves according to $dS$=$\mu$$Sdt$ + $\sigma$$SdB$. A contract has a payoff at expiration of $V_T$=$(S_T)^3$. What is the value of $V_0$ of the contract at $t=0$?

Express your answer in terms of $r, T, \sigma, \mu$  and  $S_0$

I tried to tackle this problem using Ito's Lemma but it doesn't seem to give me the right answer. Is there any way I can use $r$ as the risk-neutral rate?

Comment: Hint: write down the explicit solution of $S_T$. It is a exponential (geometric Brownian motion). Then calculate $E[e^{-rT}S_T^3]\,.$

Comment: How do I get the explicit solution? Is it through Ito's Lemma or is there some other special method?

Comment: The explicit solution of $dS=\mu S\,dt+\sigma SdB$ is well-known: $S_T=S_0\exp(\sigma B_T-\sigma^2T/2+\mu T)\,.$ It can be verified using Ito's lemma.